# Can we Increase the gain of mic of an android phone?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to increase the gain of the mic of an android phone so that it will be capable of hearing very minute sounds.Is it possible? Can you please help me with this.

Comment: i am trying to hear the heartbeat through mobile...so for that i need a more sensitive mic. if we could increase the gain of the mic it will be helpful for me

Comment: Interesting. Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) should bring you further. use setStreamVolume(...) to set volume higher. but note that there is a maximum that can be asked for by calling getStreamMaxVolume(...). so mic gain is probably limited by hardware i would guess. so it is rather not possible to do this "on-fly" but what about recording a bit, trying to amplify a special frequency by [equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) and then recognize something like a heartbeat? sounds hard but maybe possible.

Comment: which one of the listed streams is for the mic?