# android audiomanager change gain

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am developing an app to record voice.
I would like to increase the GAIN of the MIC.

Do I have to use AudioManager to do it or something during Audiorecord process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to useful links regarding this question are at:

[Can we Increase the gain of mic of an android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780382/can-we-increase-the-gain-of-mic-of-an-android-phone)

I would try the setStreamVolume() approach initially though this is going to depend on the hardware and drivers of the device as well.  Because there are so many different manufacturers and devices you may have trouble establishing a solid baseline value.